# Using partial with paper trail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paper-trail-gem

I'm trying to put some code in a partial from my show page in /events. The code works fine when I use it in my show page, but when i extract it to a partial I'm getting a No Method Error

```
undefined method `event' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_PaperTrail_Version:0x007f4368823a68>
```

**versions/_version.html.erb**

```
<% cache version do %>
  <div class="feed-item">
    <h4>
      <%= link_to version.item.name, version.item %> 
      <small>
      <%= version.event + "d" %> by <%= link_to User.find(version.whodunnit).username, User.find(version.whodunnit) %>
      </small>
    </h4>

    <ul class="list-unstyled">
      <% version.changeset.each do |data| %>
        <li>
          <strong><%= data[0].capitalize %>:</strong> 
          <% if data[1][0].present? %><p class="red">- <%= data[1][0] %></p><% end %> 
           <p class="green">+ <%= data[1][1] %></p>
        </li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<%= render :partial => '/versions/version', :object => @versions %>
```

**events controller**

```
  def show
    @versions = @event.versions
  end
```

**events model**

```
has_paper_trail
```

Any idea how i could put my code in a partial instead of having it inside my show view? Thanks.

**EDIT:**
I still get a No Method Error

```
undefined method `item' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_PaperTrail_Version:0x007f43688ee1a0>
```

**events_controller.rb**

```
before_action :set_event, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

def set_event
  @event = Event.find(params[:id])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have defined the `@event`variable in the eventscontroller?
The `@event.versions` method has to be called on an actual event object.

For example

```
def show
  @event = Event.find(1)
  @versions = @event.versions
end
```

Comment: Im using rails 4, using the set_event method. But i still get a "no method error" while using my partial.

Comment: does your `show` method look like this? Can you `Rails.logger.debug @versions` in the controller method and see if you actually have versions for your event?